# How to get the value of the base pointer, stack pointer and saved base pointer

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, stack

I know how to use gdb and used info frame but I can't find the value of the base, stack and saved base pointer. How do I get these? Can I find them in the information info frame gives me or do I have to do something else?

Comment: If you want to see value of registers in another frame, use frame N (or up/down) to select frame, then do info reg, as abligh explained.

Answer (score 5):

`info reg` will tell you the contents of the registers, including the stack pointer (`rsp` on 64 bit x86) and base pointer (`rbp` on 64 bit x86):

```
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x401340 4199232
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x0  0
rdx            0x7fffffffe608   140737488348680
rsi            0x7fffffffe5f8   140737488348664
rdi            0x0  0
rbp            0x0  0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffe508   0x7fffffffe508
r8             0x7ffff7dd4e80   140737351863936
r9             0x7ffff7dea560   140737351951712
r10            0x7fffffffe2d0   140737488347856
r11            0x7ffff7a50290   140737348174480
r12            0x4013e2 4199394
r13            0x7fffffffe5f0   140737488348656
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x7ffff7a50290   0x7ffff7a50290 <__GI_exit>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

The remaining info is available via `info frame`:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffe510:
 rip = 0x7ffff7a50290 in __GI_exit (exit.c:104); saved rip = 0x40134d
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffe520
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffe500, args: status=0
 Locals at 0x7fffffffe500, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffe510
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7fffffffe508
```